# How to make the date format of the cell different from the date format in the Fx field of Excel for the same date?

Tags: python, excel, format

How to achieve different date formats for the cell and fx field in Excel using python?

I have tried `num_format`, but that is not working

[Screenshot of how I want the date to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If9AV.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see the screenshot,may be it will be clear after that.

Comment: How will depend of what module you are using which you have not indicated.

Comment: Am fine with anything that makes it work